# Programatically replace String Array in a ListView Array Adapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView that i have populated with a string array: `{"1","2","3"}` using an Array Adapter.

```
   (ListView) ListOptions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListOptions);
    String[] exampleString = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,exampleString);
    ListOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Later on, i want to be able to change `exampleString` to `exampleString2`:

```
{"4","5","6"}
```

and have the ListView update with `exampleString2` displayed as the list options.

is there something i can do along the lines of:

```
adapter.ChangeStringArray(exampleString2);
ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to avoid having to create a new adapter each time I change the String array that is populating the list items.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayAdapter` has methods for managing the backing data array.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
adapter.addAll(exampleString);
```

---

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(exampleString2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I guess you just have to create your own `ArrayList`